# How to get fragment expiration date in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I need to get expire or creation time for cache entry.

This is for: [sitemap index](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=71453), each sitemap in index is cached action. I want to add 
`<lastmod>` attribute, which, in my case, will be cache entry creation time.

For example for action caching:

```
class ProductsController < ActionController
  caches_action :index

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
end
```

I need something like this:

```
Rails.cache.get(:controller=>'products',:action=>'index').created_at
```

Comment: Are you trying to sweep the cache? Rails has built in cache sweeping just so you know.

Comment: @DevinM it's for sitemap index, I edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution, which work with all popular cache stores (tested with redis_store, mem_cache_store, memory_store, file_store).

```
Time.at(Rails.cache.send(:read_entry,'cache/entry/key',{})).created_at)
```

`read_entry` method returns `ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry` object  ([class documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Entry.html))

Comment: I wonder why Rails doesn't expose the entry itself. Super useful. Thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: Symbol Error

`Time.at(Rails.cache.send(:read_entry,'cache/entry/key',{}).created_at)`

not 

`Time.at(Rails.cache.send(:read_entry,'cache/entry/key',{})).created_at)`

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, in Rails 4.2+, you have access in a similar way to @rogal111's answer by way of...

```
Time.at(Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, key, {}).expires_at)
# And
Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, key, {}).expired?
```

But unless you want to reach through into the object, you can't access `created_at`.

To do so you'd need to do something to the effect of

```
Rails.cache.send(:read_entry, key, {}).instance_variable_get('@created_at')
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my day! Really appreciate your answer.