# How to get cache expiration date in Rails 3 using the Dalli gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached, dalli

I have a Rails 3 application that uses the Dalli gem to manage its cache.

I need to check if a certain part of the application is setting the expiration date of the cache correctly, but can't find a way to manually check that on a specific fragment.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243846/how-to-get-fragment-expiration-date-in-rails-3-1), but it doesn't work with Dalli.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a mistake when use read_entry method.

   ```
   Rails.cache.send(:read_entry,'cache/entry/key',{})
   ```

   **The 'cache/entry/key' should not begin with the namespace.**

   for example:

   The namespace is 'aaa', the key is 'aaa:a_key_name', then the 'cache/entry/key' should be 'a_key_name'.
2. this script may work: https://gist.github.com/bkimble/1365005